# Returning user profile, and debugging

Tags: visualforce, debugging, debug

I am not returning the correct profile. I have recently had this working but it isn't now. 
Am also having issues debugging.  The debug line

```
system.debug(userProfileName);
```

gives me an error:

```
unexpected token: ')'
```

Is this incorrect syntax to debug? I have used debug before!

```
public class OppTabChooser {
    public String userProfileName {
        get {
            return [
                    select Profile.Name
                    from User
                    where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()
                    ].Profile.Name;
        }
    }
    system.debug(userProfileName);
    public String tabToLoad {
        get {
                        if (userProfileName ==  'NewAccountsManager'){
                        tabtoLoad='NewAcc';
                        }
                        if (userProfileName == ' CMManagement'){
                        tabtoLoad='cmmgmt';
                        }
                        if (userProfileName == 'Ops'){
                        tabtoLoad='clear';
                        }
                       if (userProfileName == 'System Administrator'){
                        tabtoLoad='cmmgmt';
                        }
                        else{
                        tabtoLoad = 'tabdetails';
                        }
                     return tabToLoad;              
            }
            set ;
        }

    public OppTabChooser (ApexPages.StandardController c) {
    }


}
```

Other error on this version:

```
public String userProfileName {
        get {
            return [
                    select Profile.Name
                    from User
                    where Id = :Userinfo.getUserId()
                    ].Profile.Name;
            system.debug(userProfileName);
        }
        set;

    }
```

Error:

```
Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement.
```

Comment: I think your debug statement should be inside a method. It is executable not assignment. You should put the debug where you are trying to access your property.

Comment: hmm, have added a new version with new error

Comment: Also I think your tabtoLoad will always return tabdetails unless it's a system administrator profile.

Comment: You should put system debug before return statement.

Comment: how could i systemdebug first? it was working....

Comment: why only for system admin?>

Comment: Well I certainty don't have an idea about that but according to me executables should be inside a method.  What is the issue you are facing except debugging

Comment: It is because of the if else condition. Let's say the profile is OPS. The first time the value in tabtoload will be CLEAR. Then it goes to the else block and assign CMMGMT because it didn't satisfied system administrator profile condition. I think you should use else if else if in all

Comment: Ok, this I think is describing the issue. So in any list of If it would work only for the last option before the Else? I am not sure how to process then

Comment: I will write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting correct profile name, the problem is in your getter of tabToload property.

It will always return cmgmt for System Administrator and tabdetails for every other profile. You should use if-else-if in your getter.

```
if (userProfileName ==  'NewAccountsManager'){
                        tabtoLoad='NewAcc';
                        }
                       Else if (userProfileName == ' CMManagement'){
                        tabtoLoad='cmmgmt';
                        }
                       Else if (userProfileName == 'Ops'){
                        tabtoLoad='clear';
                        }
                       Else if (userProfileName == 'System Administrator'){
                        tabtoLoad='cmmgmt';
                        }
                        else{
                        tabtoLoad = 'tabdetails';
                        }
Return tabtoload;
```

Also you were receiving the debug statement issue as executable statements should be inside a method and you should not write another statement after the return statement.

Comment: I see it working now. Thanks for showing me the Else if.